# SparkSession doesen't read database despite correct configuration

Tags: apache-spark, session, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying running this simple function using Spark 3.0.0 using Zeppelin 0.9.0:

```
def getSession(uri: String) : SparkSession = {
return SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("TEST")
      .config( "spark.mongodb.input.database", uri)
      .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome")
      .getOrCreate()}
```

Despite the configuration it's correct, i receive this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing database name. Set via the 'spark.mongodb.input.uri' or 'spark.mongodb.input.database' property
```

I really don't have idea why this is not working. Before a Zeppelin update, this function worked correctly.
We have updated Zeppelin to 0.9.0 from 0.9.0preview but i don't know hoe this can influence this. Someone have any idea?

Comment: It seems you are passing uri to `spark.mongodb.input.database`. You should probably use `spark.mongodb.input.uri`

Comment: I tried both of them but i met same result

Comment: The exact same error?

Comment: Yes i keep meeting the same identical error

Comment: Any updates? I too encountered this error

Comment: Sadly nope, that task is still WIP